# chained overloaded operators cause segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading

I am learning for my finals and try to overload some operators for my class player. Compiling is fine. But when I try to run the program I get the following error:
segmentation fault (core dumped).
I never really had this error, because I am learning, but I guess that my programm tried to write on memory, which wasn't allocated. But I have no Idea why.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "overload.h"

    using namespace std;

    player::player(int lvl2, int iq2, int s2){
        lvl=lvl2;
        iq=iq2;
        s=s2;
    }
    player::player(){
        lvl=1;
        iq=10;
        s=10;
    }
    bool player::maxlvl(){
        if(lvl < 100)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    void player::lvlup(){
        lvl=lvl+1;
        iq=iq+3;
        s=s+3;
    }

    void player::skillup(int iq2, int s2){
        if(iq2+s2<5){
            iq=iq+iq2;
            s=s+s2;
        }else{
            cout << "Not enaugh skillpoints" << endl;
        }
    }
//operator+ is a friend function defined in the header    
    player& operator+(const player& lhs, const player& rhs){
        player p;
        p.lvl = lhs.lvl + rhs.lvl;
        p.iq = lhs.iq + rhs.iq;
        p.s = lhs.s + rhs.s;
        return p;
    }
//operator- and operator= are member functions defined in the header
    player& player::operator-(const player& rhs){
        player p;
        p.lvl=this->lvl-rhs.lvl;    
        p.iq = this->iq + rhs.iq;
        p.s = this->s + rhs.s;
        return p;
    }
    player& player::operator=(const player& rhs){
        player p;
        p.lvl =rhs.lvl;
        p.iq=rhs.iq;
        p.s=rhs.s;
        return p;
    }

    int main(){
        player p1(10,32,24); //creates player with lvl=10, iq=32, s=24
        player p2; //creates player with lvl=1, iq=10, s=10
        player p3; //creates player with lvl=1, iq=10, s=10
        p2.lvlup(); //set values of p2: lvl=2, iq=13, s=13
        p3=p1+p2; //should add p1 and p2. And overwrites the values of p3
        cout << p1.lvl << " " << p1.iq << " " << p1.s <<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

The overloaded operators works fine if I use them alone.
Like p1+p2 works. p3=p1 works aswell. But chaning these operators doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't return local `player p;` by reference.

Comment: how should I do this? When I change the output (from player& to player) the operators doesn't work at all.

Comment: When I don't use the operator= It does work. But how would i overload it. And why does it work?

Comment: All the operators you've overloaded are simply wrong.

Comment: ok. So could you tell me how do I overload them? I saw it on tutorialspoint like that and with the code from tutorialspoint it worked.

Comment: Visit the Operator overloading post...